# How do I import a bootstrap theme into Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, themes, ruby-on-rails-6

I've gotten bootstrap to work, but where exactly do I add vendor files from the theme into my rails 6 application? In the themes vendor folder there are libraries like AOS and OwlCarousel with a js file and css file... i just have no clue where to put them, and how to get them to work.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to do this but I think this is the easiest.

1. You can add the `css` file to the `app/assets/stylesheets` folder.
2. Add the `css` file to the `application.css` file by importing it:

   `// application.css`

   `@import "theme";`

Update:

For the javascript:

You can add to the `application.js`

`//= require your.js`

Comment: What about the javascript libraries? They are not working how they should. Do i put them in packs, or the vendor folder?